# How to retrieve a full list of payment methods and shipping methods/codes

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods, payment-methods

I'm working on a Magento SOAP integration for a call center and am looking for a full list of configured values for the payment/credit card info and shipping methods/codes.

Because this is an integration for a call center rather than a website, we're attempting to save all the order information locally before pushing it across the SOAP api.  With this setup, I need to know all available shipping and payment option codes. (We would recreate logic on the call center side to insure invalid payment/shipping options are filtered out.)

I have attempted to use both the shoppingCartShippingList() and shoppingCartPaymentList() but those only show me available payment options for a specific shopping cart/quote that I have passed in.

Is anybody aware of an API that would show all these values without a populated cart, or the location that they would be configured in the management console/backend?

EDIT:words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not exist out of the box. Depending on whether you are using API V1, API V2, or API V2 WSI-Compliant you would need to create a small module that creates the methods that returns this info. You would also need api.xml, wsdl,xml(or wsi.xml, depending) and to add your methods to the API.